# Passing arugments to callback function

Tags: javascript, function, callback, arguments

I am trying to pass an argument to a callback function, It actually allows the argument to be passed however throws a random error saying that the variable in the callback function is not defined.

Here is the function :

```
function trackLoader(track) { 
    myPlayer[0] = new Tone.Player("Audio/" + track + ".wav", callBack);
}
```

here is the callback function :

```
function callBack() {
   myPlayer[0].loop = true;
   myPlayer[0].sync();
   myPlayer[0].start();
}
```

As you can see from above i would to simply pass the index of the player to the callback function. Thanks in advance, Matt

Comment: What variable is causing the error?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly your code is doing; `myPlayer` looks like a global above and so would be accessible to the callback. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: It depends on how `Tone.Player()` calls your callback; if it binds the `Player` instance to it, just call `this.loop = true;` and so on

Comment: It would help if you share actual error

Comment: Sorry I didn't make that clear enough, There isn't an error present on the code above, however if i try to pass an argument though the callback function i then throws an error.

Comment: @MatthewTindall If you simply replace `callback` with `callback(0)` it won't work; you would have to replace it with `function () { callback(0); }`. That's because `callback(0)` is a function *call* that returns nothing, so you'd now be passing `undefined` instead of `callback`

Comment: When you pass a callback to a function written by somebody else, you have no control over the arguments that are passed to the callback. If you need your own arguments, store them in a global variable and use that in your callback.

Comment: cheers @ChrisG that makes sense now, not had an previous experience with using callback functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tone.Player is gonna call your callback function without parameters. You can give to it an anonymous function that's gonna call the callback with the index you want.

---

```
function trackLoader(track) {
   const index = 0;

   myPlayer[index] = new Tone.Player('Audio...wav', () => callBack(index));
}
```

---

```
function callBack(index) {
   myPlayer[index].loop = true;
   myPlayer[index].sync();
   myPlayer[index].start();
}
```

---

---

**PS: I think `Tone.Player` will callback special data in case of error. You should definitely check that out.**

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest making the variable global, it should work but I'm not quite sure this will be the best solution.

```js
var myPlayer;

function trackLoader(track) {
  myPlayer[0] = new Tone.Player("Audio/" + track + ".wav", callBack);
}

function callBack() {
  myPlayer[0].loop = true;
  myPlayer[0].sync();
  myPlayer[0].start();
}
```

Comment: Dear downvoter, please explain the reason for the downvote.

Comment: OP isn't getting an error with his current code, he is getting an error when he tries to change the code in a way he thinks allows him to pass the index. You fixed an error that never existed in the first place.